# When does onSecondaryTap in GestureDetector gets called in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, gesturedetector

Since we have onDoubleTap in GestureDetector, I wondered if onSecondaryTap actually the second finger touches the screen?
Then I tried that, but this is not the case.

I also have tried using two fingers touching the screen, but this is not the case either.

So does anyone knows when does it gets called?

Thank you

Comment: Did you find an answer in the meanwhile? I have the same problem. I want to detect when zooming starts.

Comment: ok, meanwhile I found out I need to use onScaleStart+onScaleUpdate+onScaleEnd instead of onTapStart+onTapUpdate+OnTapEnd to get the pinch information from the ScaleUpdateDetails.

Comment: It seems to be the right click of a mouse button. Not sure if this is true though. Anyone can comment?